# scatter plot between two different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have two different datasets. Two different data frames. I would like to generate scatterplot for this.

```
Dataset1:

MT  NUM
D   103
M   67
D   90
W   456
MM  78
M   434

Dataset2:

MT  NUM
M   13
M   6
MM  9
W   45
D   7
```

Scatterplot should look something like following:
[image]

I don't have any idea how to generate the plot. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thank you

I used following code: But the plot looks completely different from what I want.

```
library(reshape)
hh <- melt(list(p1 = Dataset1, p2 = Dataset2), id.vars = "MT")

ggplot(hh, aes(MT, value, colour = L1)) + geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual("Dataset", values = c("p1" = "blue", "p2" = "red"))
```

Comment: Hi Raju!  There are many ways to do this that aren't too hard, but it will help us to know what your data structures are.  Are these two different data frames?  named vectors?  Please give us some sample *code* to generate the data structures you're working with -- even if it's only a few rows long, like you did with the data.

Comment: Yes, they are two different data frames. And I posted the code above which I tried. I also got a plot with that. But that is not what I want. I need a plot which looks like above.

Comment: You haven't given us any code to generate Dataset1 and Dataset2.  That's the final piece to have a reproducible example.

Comment: There are just data frames. Why you need code for that.

Comment: If you are plotting `MT` on the x-axis, those values are categorical not numeric. So perhaps a bar/column chart is more appropriate. It's also not clear how you are trying to specify colour; where is L1 coming from, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that's what you want, as the graph you show differs a lot from what you obtain from the code you wrote.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'MT')
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(NUM.x, NUM.y), color = '#0087E9', size = 5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = 'black', size = 16),
        axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'))
```

[image]

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(MT = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("D", 
"M", "MM", "W"), class = "factor"), NUM = c(103L, 67L, 90L, 456L, 
78L, 434L)), .Names = c("MT", "NUM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(MT = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("D", 
"M", "MM", "W"), class = "factor"), NUM = c(13L, 6L, 9L, 45L, 
7L)), .Names = c("MT", "NUM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: This looks fine. But I need different colours for the two data frame values. And also legend showing the colors.

Comment: Each point takes its `x` from `df1` and its `y` from `df2`, so there is no such thing as 'two data frames' anymore. I assumed that's what you wanted, based on the displayed graph. Evidently it's wrong, pls explain better (edit the question) what you want.

Comment: Ok. I got the plot I need with some changes. Nothing major one. Thank you !!